# Разработка Windows 8 на HTML/JS

Tags: windows, html, windows-8, javascript, html5

подскажите книжечки или мануалы по программированию под windows 8 на html/js... От нуля с рассмотрением самой процедуры разработки

Comment: посмелюсь спросить, а почему именно по windows 8? js он и в линуксе и в хрюше и в семерке js. Та же ситуация с html. Работа js зависит только от браузера. По js советую 6 издание Девида Фленегана Javascript - Подробное руководство. По ХТМЛ столько материалов в интернете, хоть пруд пруди.

Comment: Microsoft дали возможность разработки приложений Windows Store на html5/js. Причем здесь браузеры?

Comment: Вот именно - Максим правильно понял вопрос. Браузер нафиг мне не приснился - я то прогаю в них давно,как мне это все дело перенести на платформу Windows 8 чтоб как приложение работало

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Dr. Doris Chen's Blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dorischen/)
2. [Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/)
3. [Creating JavaScript/HTML5 Windows 8 Applications](https://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/creating-javascripthtml5-metro-applications.html)
4. [David Rousset Blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davrous/)

И еще есть неплохая книжка на эту тему, автор - Walter Steffen. Найдете сами :)